# String manipulation using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I am wondering how I would remove the vowels from a word on a button click?

Here is what I am trying to do - http://www.marcia.bnmla.com/~marcia/project0.html

I need to use jQuery to remove the vowels in the second box so it displays only consonants when you click the button. I have it where it displays "MRC" as text when the button is clicked and I need to redo it using string manipulation so I can change the word to anything in my code and it will remove the vowels in that word. I am obviously new at this. Please help me!

Here is my code:

```
<div id="marcia_box">
        <p id="marciatext">marcia</p>
        <div id="marcia_boxBtn"><button id="marciaBtn">Marcia</button></div>
</div>

$("#marciaBtn").click(function() {
    $("#marcia_box").css("background-color","#999");
    $("#marciatext").html('mrc');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery allows you to pass a function to `.html`, which should return a new HTML string. jQuery will pass the old HTML, so you can do something like this:

```
$("#marciatext").html(function(i, current) {
  return current.replace(/[aeiou]/g, "");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you really need jQuery? What about plain old JavaScript?

```
"abcdef".replace(/[aeiou]/gi, "")  // => "bcdf"
```

How's that?

Answer (score 1):

**[demo](http://jsbin.com/utakef/3/edit)**

This one will help you now and in the future for other transformations
specially for
 **toggling between two array keys**

```
var c=0, text=['marcia', 'mrc'];

$("#marciaBtn").click(function() {
    $("#marciatext").html( text[ ++c%2 ] );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown by Jarrett Meyer, removing the vowels has nothing with the jQuery part. But just to show you how to put it together with jQuery (since you said you is really new in it), here is a sample:

```
$("#marciatext").text($("#marciatext").text().replace(/[aeiou]/gi, ""));
```